# urllib.error.URLError unknown url type 'https>

Tags: python, https, urllib

Im using this script to parse a site and download files but it keeps returning the same error. I was under the assumption that **urllib.parse.encode** and urllib.parse.urljoin but it was unclear how or where I would use it.

I have reinstalled python 3.4, 3.6, and pycharm, installed Openssl with no avail.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urljoin, urlencode
import lxml
import os

class tools():
    def get_page(*args):
        headers = headers = {}
        headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17"
        req = urllib.request.Request(args, headers=headers)
        resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        respData = resp.read()
        return respData


class Advisorshares():
    def productscreener():
        '''Creates a csv of the list of ets advisor shares holds'''
        url = ('https://www.advisorshares.com/etfs')
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(tools.get_page(url), "lxml")
        table = soup.find('table')
        links = []
        tickers = []

        for i in range(0,len(table.find_all('a')),2):
            tag = table.find_all('a')[num]
            links.append(tag.get('href'))
            tickers.append(tag.text)

    def download():
        Advisorshares.productscreener()
        os.cwd('/')
        for i in tickers:
            base = urlencode('http://www.advisorshares.com/holdings-file/')
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(base + i, i + '.csv')


Advisorshares.download()
```

> > Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydev_run_in_console.py", line 52, in run_file Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul 8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) # execute the script File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev_pydev_imps_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
> > File "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/webscraper/venv/src/webscraper.py", line 91, in  Advisorshares.download()
> > File "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/webscraper/venv/src/webscraper.py", line 84, in download Advisorshares.productscreener()
> > File "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/webscraper/venv/src/webscraper.py", line 73, in productscreener soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(tools.get_page(url), "lxml") File "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/webscraper/venv/src/webscraper.py", line 14, in get_page resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req) File "C:\Program >Files\Python36\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
> > File "C:\ProgramFiles\Python36\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open response = self._open(req, data) File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 549, in _open 'unknown_open', req)
> > File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain result = func(*args) File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 1388, in unknown_open raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type) urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: ('https>

Answer (score -1):

You problem is that you are giving a tuple to `get_page` which can't be interpreted correct by `urllib.request.Request`. All you have to do is change this line:

```
req = urllib.request.Request(args, headers=headers)
```

To this line

```
req = urllib.request.Request(*args, headers=headers)
```

So the `args` will be interpreted as arguments for `urllib.request.Request`